# node.js discord bot use input as bot output and reactions

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

So I have a few things i need a hand with. I want the user to be able to input multiple lines of text and then the bot uses those lines of text as an output. for example.

**user input**

Ben
england london
500000
+15

now i want to bot to read those arguments and use them in its output. so for "england london" that would be classed as 2 separate arguments.. so the bot would dosplay that as

country: England
city: London.

My next issue is reactions on an embedded text from the bot. i have the reactions setup but i would like to edit the embedded text when someone reacts and populate a field with their @. if they un-react, then edit again and remove their @. I would like to do this using 4 emotes so a total of 4 users will be mentioned in the embedded text via their @'s

this is my current code;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "mytoken";
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const prefix = '!';



client.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log('Boost Bot Is Online')
    client.user.setActivity("Mythic+", {type: "PLAYING"});    
})
  

let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(3, 10) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(3, 10);

client.on("message", messsage=>{

    let args  = messsage.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'hello':
            messsage.channel.send(' Hello');
            break;

        case 'e':
            const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#c731c7') // embed colour DONE
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/ZpXw8vX.png')
            .setTitle(messsage.member.user.tag) // username who used command DONE
            .addFields(
                { name: '**Run ID**', value: r}, // need to make random 10 digit alphanumerical generator DONE
                { name: '**Comment**', value: 'Some value here' }, // Standard comment from command (in text)
                { name: '**Boosters**', value: 'Some value here' }, // users @ has to be mentioned after reaction, so bot has to edit embed.
                { name: '**Pot**', value: 'Some value here', inline: true }, // price of the run
                { name: '**Booster Cut**', value: 'Some value here', inline: true }, // 75% of pot
                { name: '**Advertiser Cut**', value: 'Some value here', inline: true }, // 15% of pot
                { name: '**Dungeon**', value: 'Some value here', inline: true }, // get number from command (if no dungeon name display ANY)
                { name: '**Payment Realm**', value: 'Some value here', inline: true }, // text from command
                { name: '**Gold Bank**', value: 'Some value here', inline: true }, // if horde display "ktcbankh" if ally display "ktcbanka"
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('Boost Bot', 'https://i.imgur.com/ZpXw8vX.png');
            messsage.channel.send(exampleEmbed) .then(sentEmbed => {
                sentEmbed.react('725452952193466380')
                sentEmbed.react('725452952424153158')
                sentEmbed.react('725452952311038086')
                sentEmbed.react('725452952529010750')
                sentEmbed.react('❌')
            })
        break;
    }
})


client.login(token);
```